# How to kill heavy process (TensorFlow Lite) running in the Scheduler.computation() in android

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java2, executorservice, tensorflow-lite

I'm newbie in the android development and now making android app that using TFLite inference (`tensorflowinferenceinterface`) which is CPU-bound, native process.

I used `RxJava 2.x` and `Schedulers.computation` to run that heavy process in the background thread. In the normal case, it runs very well.

But, the problem I met was that I want to kill the job running in the background thread when the app is minimized (`onPause`). I found and tried these methods of available threading libraries.

> 1. `Schedulers.computation().shutdown()`
> 2. `executorservice.shutdownNow()`

Although I used these methods to terminate the job running in the thread, it doesn't stop and running until the whole job is finished. I think it is because it is impossible to check interrupt signal if `tensorflowinferenceinterface.run()` is running...

**To sum it up...**

#### Condition

- Run heavy CPU-bound process in the background thread.
- Hard to access inside library code to add interrupt checking part.

#### What I want

- Kill the process in the background thread when the app is minimized (`onPauese`).

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Is it not enough to just `unsubscribe`/`dispose` in `onPause`?

Comment: @PPartisan Yes. I used `dispose` and `clear` with `CompositeDisposable` object which contains results of subscribe. However, the method doesn't finish even though I used that.